# How can I write an MDX query in Microsoft Reporting Services that displays measures names on Rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, reporting-services, ssas-2008

How can I write an MDX query in Microsoft Reporting Services that displays some  measures  names  in the fact table  and total measures (amount) associated to that measure?, and measure names should be on the rows.  For example, a  fact table has measures  as follows;

```
FK  FK2   Measure AA Measure BB
1     4           60         89
2     4           15         78
```

The MDX query should display

```
 Measure AA        149
 Measure BB         93
```

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of Reporting Services; you have to use a workaround, which is to use the MDX query *as an expression*.

```
="SELECT { ... } ON ROWS "
&"     , { ... } ON COLUMNS "
&"  FROM MyCube"
```